# No module named 'pjsua' , on ubuntu 20

Tags: python, ubuntu

import pjsua
it's my first time using pjsua library in python and i'm trying to import it on ubuntu 20 and it gives me an error -> no module named 'pjsua'
could someone help me in installing it ?

Comment: have you tried to install using [doc](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install)?

Comment: `pip install pjsua`  https://pypi.org/project/pjsua/

Comment: "./configure && make dep && make"
i'm running this on the terminal and it gives -> no such directory , 
i'm sorry i'm new in using linux

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a library from 2014 whose maintainer specifically tells you to use a different library instead?

Comment: i noticed that the library no longer exists , i tried looking for another library that has the same functionality .
what i'm trying to do is recieving and sending calls .

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m pip install pjsua
```

Enter this in the command line

Comment: gives me -> No module named pip

Comment: Do you not have pip installed?

Comment: Try https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/